# Remove inflections at end of lines from geom_line()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the predictions of a lmer model with the following code:

```
p1 <- ggplot(Mac_Data_Tracking, aes(x = Rspan, y = SubjEff, colour = NsCond)) + 
geom_point(size=3) + 
geom_line(data=newdat, aes(y=predict(SubjEff.model,newdata=newdat)),lineend="round") 
print(p1)
```

I get weird inflections at the end of each line, is there a way to remove them? I have changed the data in newdat, but the lines always have these inflections.

Lines with Inflections at ends:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with having 2 x values, actually...it was having 2 subject values.

The linear mixed model is:
Mixed.model <- lmer(Outcome ~ NsCond + Rspan + (1|Subject), data=Data))

For newdat, I was intially using:

```
newdat <- expand.grid(Subject=c(min(Data$Subject),max(Data$Subject)),Rspan=c(min(Data$Rspan), max(Data$Rspan)),NsCond=unique(Data$NsCond))
```

Which gave me:

```
       Subject     Rspan NsCond
1        1 0.2916667   Pink
2       18 0.2916667   Pink
3        1 1.0000000   Pink
4       18 1.0000000   Pink
5        1 0.2916667 Babble
6       18 0.2916667 Babble
7        1 1.0000000 Babble
8       18 1.0000000 Babble
9        1 0.2916667   Loss
10      18 0.2916667   Loss
11       1 1.0000000   Loss
12      18 1.0000000   Loss
```

For each Rspan (x) there are 2 "Subjects" (1 and 18).

I changed newdat to:

```
newdat <- expand.grid(Subject=1,Rspan=c(min(Data$Rspan), max(Data$Rspan)),NsCond=unique(Data$NsCond))
```

Which results in:

```
 Subject     Rspan NsCond
1       1 0.2916667   Pink
2       1 1.0000000   Pink
3       1 0.2916667 Babble
4       1 1.0000000 Babble
5       1 0.2916667   Loss
6       1 1.0000000   Loss
```

[Now it looks good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhoEt.png)

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have `geom_line(data=newdat, aes(y=predict(SubjEff.model,newdata=newdat))`. So you've fed `newdat` to `geom_line` as the data frame to use for plotting. But then for your y-value you provide a separate vector of predictions (based on `newdat`), when `y` should actually be just a column of `newdat`. I'm not sure why that's causing the inflections at the ends (probably there are, somehow, two different y-values being provided for each of the endpoint x-values), but that's probably the source of your problem.

Instead, you should create a column in `newdat` with the predictions (if you haven't already) and feed that column name to ggplot as the `y` in `geom_line`. To add a column of predictions, do the following:

```
newdat$pred = predict(SubjEff.model,newdata=newdat)
```

You should also give `geom_line` the `x` values that correspond to the `y` values in `newdat`. So your code would be:

```
geom_line(data=newdat, aes(y=pred, x=Rspan), lineend="round")
```

(Where `Rspan` will (automatically) be the `Rspan` column in `newdat`.)

Comment: Sounds like you've got it figured out, but I've updated my answer, just in case.